# Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, app-bundle

I'm trying to make an appbundle for my app, but this warning shows up.

```
C:\Users\IMBA\AndroidStudioProjects\quizzi>flutter build appbundle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file 'C:\Users\IMBA\AndroidStudioProjects\quizzi\android\app\<C:UsersIMBAAndroidStudioProjectsquizziandroidappkey.jks>' not found for signing config 'release'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                         7.8s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

But my key.jks file was already made and my key.properties path to the key.jks file is correct.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Try to set `storeFile` property in your key.properties to `key.jks` instead of absolute path. Does it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the `key.jks` in the `android/app/` folder, just change line 4 in your `key.properties` to:
`storeFile=key.jks`.